# Find exact match or first bigger number in Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have next problem.
There is a table with four columns:

```
|ID |  X |  Y | VAL |
|:--|:--:|:--:|----:|
|1  | 1  | 1  | 1110|
|2  | 1  | 2  | 1720| 
|3  | 1  | 3  | 2330|
|4  | 1  | 4  | 2940|
|5  | 1  | 5  | 3550|
...
```

When user enter some value in text field e.g. 2370 i need function to find is there exact match in VAL field and if not to find very first bigger than 2370 (2940) and return ID value.
In some other language I can do it trough dictionaries and so one but in VBA I simply don't have idea.
Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query to get this answer, using `TOP 1` to just return 1 record:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblData.ID, tblData.VAL
FROM tblData
WHERE (((tblData.VAL)>=2370))
ORDER BY tblData.VAL ASC;
```